# Why my Form_validation always returns FALSE?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i'm trying to figure whats wrong with my code, the form validation is always return false.
here's the code snippets from my controller:

```
function edit() 
{
    //load form_validation class
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_old','password lama','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_new1','password baru','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_new2','confirm password','required|trim|xss_clean|matches[password_new1]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Lengkapi Form Dengan Benar dan Lengkap');
        redirect('admin/akun');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model("user_model","user");
        if($_POST)
        {
            $result = $this->user->edit_user($_POST);
            if($result == FALSE)
            {
                $data['page'] = $this->config->item('ci_my_admin_template_dir_admin') . "error_message";
                $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Silahkan Log In dengan Username dan Password yang baru!');
                redirect('admin/logout');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there any other configuration that i should change to make it works??

Thank you for the help..

EDIT:
SOLVED->my bad i didn't load helper('security') while adding xss_clean inside my validation rules

Comment: i think name of the input fields in view and in validation rules doesn't match,That's why returning false.So,Crosscheck names of the fields properly

Comment: After the first `else` add `echo validation_errors(); exit();` and check.

Comment: Add your view too please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Codeigniter [Input](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) class.

```
    function edit() 
    {
        //load form_validation class
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_old','password lama','required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_new1','password baru','required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_new2','confirm password','required|trim|xss_clean|matches[password_new1]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Lengkapi Form Dengan Benar dan Lengkap');
            redirect('admin/akun');
        }
        else
        {
           $data['password_old'] = $this->input->post('password_old');
           $data['password_new1'] = $this->input->post('password_new1');
           $data['password_new1'] = $this->input->post('password_new1');

            $this->load->model("user_model","user");

                $result = $this->user->edit_user($data);
                if($result == FALSE)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Silahkan Log In dengan Username dan Password yang baru!');
                    redirect('admin/logout');
                }
                else
                {
                    $data['page'] = $this->config->item('ci_my_admin_template_dir_admin') . "error_message";
                    $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);

                }

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your ellislab link is out dated and does not deal with codeIgniter any more, you can get the current and old doc's from here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs now please try and use these doc links.